# Camera sensor with an easy-to-use SDK and interface to Android or Arduino

Tags: android, sdk, camera, arduino

Is there a camera (can be point and shoot, or just the sensor) that has an SDK that can be interfaced with Android or an Arduino?

I have seen a few things online, but all of them are hacks. I like the Flea3, but it seems like you really need a full system to run this camera, or multiple cameras.

If [this Samsung camera](http://www.samsung.com/us/photography/digital-cameras/EC-ST200FBPBUS) had an open SDK for Android, that would be ideal. If it had any SDK that they released to control the camera remotely (USB or wireless), that would also be awesome.

I know GoPro has their new Wi-Fi backpack, but you can only use their application to control the camera. I want to be able to turn the camera on and off, take pictures at any interval I set, including as fast as possible, and control other camera settings that are available.

Comment: You don't seem to care about the type of camera, so what's wrong with the one already built into most android devices?

Comment: That is one option I am exploring.  The cameras on the phones are decent these days.  The application requires a higher end sensor though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something better, called Picture Transfer Protocol (PTP). CHDK has a PTP interface, and I could connect to the camera with an arduino.

http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/PTP_Extension

http://code.google.com/p/arduino-ptpusb/

Answer (score 0):

Most high-end cameras have an IR remote. An Arduino can be used to record and replay the IR codes. See [here](http://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor) for an example that shows how to capture the codes and create an intervalometer.

Comment: I had thought about that the other day, it is a viable option that I will look into.

Comment: I think I found something better, called Picture Transfer Protocol (PTP).  CHDK has a PTP interface, and I could connect to the camera with an arduino.  I feel like it is less of a hack because it uses PTP.